# Impala/Hive get list of tables along with creator and date created

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala

I'm trying to clean up some dev/test tables in Impala for my team, but can't seem to find a way to list out tables with their creator and the date last accessed.  The `show tables` command simply lists out the table names.  Because there are hundreds of tables, with less than a quarter belonging to our team, going through each table individually to see if it should be dropped would take hours.

Is there not a way to list out table names along with the creator and date created?

Edit: I can see the creator and creation date/time when I click on a table's info button in Hue, so I know the information is stored somewhere:
[image]

Comment: Are you using Kerberos with Hive? If not, there's no username attached to anything

Comment: @cricket_007 we are. In Hue, when I click on a tables information, I see the creator in the form of username@domain, creation date and time, as well as the format (ie. text) and whether it's Managed or not.  I was hoping to see this information in list form, rather than having to go down each table one by one clicking on the info button in Hue.

Comment: Added a screenshot with the info I'm able to see for each individual table.

Comment: You should be able to query the metastore for that information, not Hive itself

Comment: Posted approach for individual table as well as all table meta information, hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way around this, take each table and describe table. You need to run the following command:

```
describe formatted <your_table_name>;
```

There you can find details such as below,

> Database:
>
> Owner:
>
> CreateTime:
>
> LastAccessTime:

Other way around is, in mysql metadata is stored in hive database you can query for tables created and its meta information in below query,

```
use hive;
select * from TBLS;
```